# Cannot write a sql query to find mean sum payment in a month (taking into account periods of time)

Tags: sql, date

I have a database which shows how many products the client bought and how much money paid at the current period of time (data is given for 1 year):
(This is just a part of it)

```
date_new    id_check    id_client   count_products  sum_payment
2001-03-20  2271145      104027      2               23.31
2001-03-20  2271145      104027      1               31.75
2001-03-20  2271145      104027      1               6.8
2001-07-20  1771932      112005      1               2.15
2001-07-20  1771932      112005      1               8.63
2001-08-20  1795365      112005      1               1.37
2001-05-20  2426443      185106      1               7.97
2001-05-20  2426443      185106      8               57.97
```

I also have a task to make a query which shows person's mean_sum_payment for whole period and mean_sum_payment for a month. I do not fully understand how to make a query. I have tried this:

```
select id_client, avg(sum_payment) AS mean_sum_payment_period,
       (select avg(sum_payment)
        from transaction_info
        group by id_client, month(date_new)) AS mean_sum_payment_month
from transaction_info
group by id_client;
```

However, It doesn't work as subquery has 1 row more (because I have 4 month and 3 clients).

Please, tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(sum_payment) over (partition by id_client, year(date_new), month(date_new)) as month_avg_sum_payment,
       avg(sum_payment) over (partition by id_client) as overall_avg_sum_payment
from t;
```

`t` is whatever the first table in the question is, perhaps `transaction_info`.